# Is there a way to form this regex so that the optional group doesn't end up in the match groups?

Tags: c#, regex

I have this code for regex matching:

```
Match regexMatch(string inputStr)
{
 string numberAlphaCaptureRegex = @"^([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?)\W*([A-Z]*)$";
 return Regex.Match(inputStr,numberAlphaCaptureRegex);
}
```

which I'm intending to use to match strings like:

```
3 ##+ AST
2.54 --&! V
99.22
```

I'm matching using this code:

```
match = Regex.Match(valveName, numberAlphaCaptureRegex);
```

In the first example, I want the match to have groups `3` and `AST`, in the second `2.54` and `V`, and in the third `99.22`.  The first one works fine, but the second also includes the group `.54` and the third also includes `.22`.  I assume this is because the expression has the optional group `([.][0-9]+)?`, which I've added so that I'll pick up both integers and decimals.  Is there a way to rewrite the regex so that I'll only get the complete number?

Comment: @Tushar, that only picks up the pre-decimal portion, so I get `2` and `V` instead of `2.54` and `V`.

Comment: @Tushar never mind, it's working now, with `^([0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]+))\W*([A-Z]*)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the second capturing group to [a non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) instead:

```
string numberAlphaCaptureRegex = @"^([0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]+)?)\W*([A-Z]*)$";
```

As a side note, the second capturing group `([A-Z]*)` will sometimes match zero characters (since `*` means zero or more). To prevent this, you could change `*` to `+` (one or more), and then make the capturing group optional, `([A-Z]+)?`.

[**Live Example**](https://regex101.com/r/gH8gH6/1)

```
string numberAlphaCaptureRegex = @"^([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\W*([A-Z]+)?$";
```

Matches based on the input you provided:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-1]   `3`
2.  [6-9]   `AST`
MATCH 2
1.  [10-14] `2.54`
2.  [20-21] `V`
MATCH 3
1.  [22-27] `99.22`
```

Comment: Why did you use an escaped `\.` instead of the character class `[.]`?  Does that change the performance significantly?

Comment: @sigil I'm pretty sure it would have the same performance. I just did that out of habit since it's only a single character. It's definitely up to you.